# I am getting Notice: Undefined index: loggedin in when using SESSION

Tags: php, session

When a user is successfully authenticated, s/he is either redirected to register.php if the user has not yet signed up for training.

If the user has already signed up for training, s/he is redirected to registered.php to view/modify his or her training classes.

So far, this works fine.

Problem is if user attempts to go directly to register.php or registered.php, s/he gets into any of the web pages without logging in first.

This is what I am trying to prevent but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: loggedin in .... on line 3
 Please log in first to see this page
```

Here is what I am using so far and thanks for your help.

```
//login.php

 $user = trim($_POST['user']);
 $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);

     // hash to sanitize the input further
    $pass = md5($pass);

   $tSQL = "SELECT u.empl_first, u.username FROM users u inner join Training t on u.Employee_Id = t.Employee_ID WHERE USERNAME = ?
    and PASSWORD = ? ";

    $params = array($user, $pass, $params);
    $sqll = sqlsrv_query($con, $tSQL);

if ($objResult = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqll, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $firstname = $objResult["empl_first"];
    $_SESSION["firstname"] = $objResult["empl_first"];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header('location:registered.php');
  }
  else
    header("location:register.php?user='".ms_escape_string($user)."'&pass='".ms_escape_string($pass)."' ");

sqlsrv_close($con);

?>
```

//register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] != true) {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page";
}
```

Comment: Give this line of code a good coat of looking at `if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] != true)` .... and then fix it to remove your `undefined index error`

Comment: on login page also start session.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, that's for that nice code. I am still getting the same error though.

BTW: Yes, I do have session_start(); at the very top of the page. Understanding why the error is the key to figuring this out.

Thanks a lot again

Comment: Do you mean yo uare still getting the undefined index error? If so on what line number does the error happen? Are you sure it is still the line you show from `register.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I had to close the browser and re-open it rather than refreshing it. After doing so, now, two things are happening.

Firs, the error is gone - thank God for that. However, when I log in successfully, I still see my custom message that says "Please log in first to see this page". The message should not be there if you successfully log in.

The other issue is when I try to get to that page directly without logging in, it still lets me in with same custom message at top of page. Any thoughts on why these are happening.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes:-

In `login.php` start the session using `session_start();` at the top of the script, so that the code that sets variables in `$_SESSION` will work.

In `register.php` change the IF statement from

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] != true)
```

To

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] != true)
```

then the IF will not test `$_SESSION['loggedin'] != true` if the variable is found to not exist by the first part of the IF i.e. `!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])`

Comment: working now. I had  $_SESSION['loggedin'] on wrong line.

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

On login.php have `session_start();` somewhere on the top.

On each script that you use the session you must have it.